# Why Rotated UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage

I did nothing but setting up my captured image into `UIImageview`

- No extra custom settings
- No transformation
- No resizing, nothing

Then why my image view returns rotated image.

I found the solution using

```
UIImage* rotatedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage 
                                 scale:1.0 
                                 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
```

Now, I get original image. But though I just want to know the reason for `automatic rotated image`.

Note: this happens only when picture is captured from cam, if we choose picture from gallery then it doesn't get rotated & looks proper.

Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

This could depend on the extra "shooting information" eventually added by your camera. E.g. if you take a picture with an iPhone in portrait mode ("vertical") then the image will still have the original size (2048x1536) but with the "orientation" shooting information set to "rotate 90deg". Probably UIImageView doesn't read the shooting information and show the image as "raw", that is rotated (this is the image that has been physically taken by the sensor).

Consider this: if you rotate the iPhone the physical sensor will be rotated too and the iPhone "artificially" shows the image for you to display is correctly.

You can check this by taking two photos with your iPhone, in both orientations, and then connecting the iPhone to your Mac and start the "Image Capture" app. You will see that the two photos have the same size but one will be rotated vertically. You can check the shooting information instead using Preview.

As far as the "picture taken from gallery", my guess is that the gallery does the orientation for you and returns to you not the raw image but the image after the orientation has been applied (exactly as you did in your code).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.I have captured a picture using both portrait & lanscape mode. But it returns the same result. that is rotated image. Portrait mode returns UIImageOrientationLeft while Landscape returns UIImageOrientationRightMirrored. :(

Comment: The Right-Mirrored orientation sounds strange. Did you capture it using the iPhone iOS photo camera? did you manipulate it using the internal Photo app? (e.g. crop or else).

Comment: I captured using internal Photo app, & used original image. didn't crop anything